# SVN merge individual file revisions from a branch into trunk

Tags: svn, merge

I have a couple of fixes I've done on a branch that I want merged back into the trunk.  I do not want to merge the whole branch into the trunk, just the few branch checkins I've done.  What's the correct syntax for doing this?

TY,
Fred

Comment: Did the_mandrills answer work? I have the same problem but since you haven't accepted I'm not sure if I should try it or not.

Answer (score 39):

I'm not sure exactly what you're asking as the title talks about merging single files but the text of the question talks about single revisions.  In the case of merging single revisions you need: (to merge the changes committed in revisions 100, 105, 115)

```
cd trunk
svn merge -c 100 -c 105 -c 115 http://..../branches/mybranch .
```

If you want to merge only the part of revision 100 that affects file.cpp:

```
cd trunk/path/to/file.cpp
svn merge -c 100 http://../branches/mybranch/path/to/file.cpp file.cpp
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to merge the whole branch.
Starting in svn 1.5, information on what was merged is stored in the repo - in the `svn:mergeinfo` property.  If you merge an individual file `svn:mergeinfo` will be set deep in the tree.  When someone tries to do a merge from the top of the project, `svn:mergeinfo` won't exist and they'll have to decide to take that changeset.  If you really don't want it to get merged you should merge from the top of the project and then only commit the top level directory (`svn:mergeinfo` will be the only change) and the file you want.

[Way more than anyone ever wanted to know about mergeinfo](http://www.collab.net/community/subversion/articles/merge-info.html)

Comment: To understand what is being explained here, go here for an even better explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12732085/1420441