# How do I merge PART of a file in SVN?

Tags: svn, svn-merge

Say I have made multiple changes to a file, but I only wish to commit a few of those changes back to trunk, i.e. lines 10-20 need committing but nothing else, is there a way to do this in SVN? Ideally using Tortoise SVN.

I'm not working on a branch, just on a checkout from trunk. I'm just committing a few obvious fixes nothing development related, mostly odd bits in makefiles.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe commit changes you want to merge in separate commit, and then merge only this commit?
I think it [may be related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3876854/svn-merge-individual-file-revisions-from-a-branch-into-trunk)

Comment: I did spot that one, but that question regards merging specific COMMITS in a branch, mine regards checking in specific changes in file(s) in a checkout. I thought there might be some sort of interactive merge where I can essentially generate a patch interactively, but it's not obvious.