# Is it "safe" to merge individual files between branches in SVN?

Tags: svn, version-control, merge

The question of how you can merge individual files in SVN has been [answered before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3876854/svn-merge-individual-file-revisions-from-a-branch-into-trunk), so my question is: Is it safe to do so? Will SVN "get" that specific files have already been merged if I end up merging the whole branch at some point? And what if I merge changes back and forth before I merge the whole branch?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, you can merge individual files, but it's usually considered *bad practice* to do so.

The problem is that Subversion uses the `svn:mergeinfo` to track merges. If a file doesn't have this `svn:mergeinfo` property, it uses the `svn:mergeinfo` of a parent directory. When you merge individual files hither and thither, all those files now get their own `svn:mergeifno` property on them.

Does this cause a *real* problem? No. Subversion works fine. The problem is merely perceived. Every time Subversion updates the `svn:mergeinfo` property, it creates another version of that file even though the *contents* of that file haven't changed.

Where this is a problem is when you do a merge of a trunk to a branch (or visa versa). You run a command like this:

```
$ svn merge http://svn.mycorp.com/svn/project/trunk .
```

You see 100+ files that were modified, but you **know** that only 3 or 4 files should have been merged.

Examining these files, you discover the only difference is that the `svn:mergeinfo` property was changed to show that you've merged the latest stuff to these files (even though it doesn't change the content of the file themselves). No real issue. Simply allow Subversion to *update* these files' `svn:mergeinfo` property on the commit, and everything is fine. Yes, the merge will show 100+ files were changed in the commit if you do a `svn log`, but a careful review will show you that only their `svn:mergeinfo` properties were changed.

What you should not do is *revert* these files. That will mark that the changes weren't merged into those files (even though it didn't change their contents). Next merge will attempt to remerge the previous merge and cause even more havoc.

Sometimes when developers see this they start complaining to me about the modifications. After all, why are these files modified if there's no change in the file themselves? They get frustrated by all of the `svn:mergeinfo` changes.

That's why it's considered *best practice* to always merge at the root of your project and not individual files. This way, only the directory at the root of your project gets the `svn:mergeinfo` property, and all of the other files in your project will simply use that `svn:mergeinfo` property.

If you and all of your developers understand this, and are willing to *put up* with this behavior, there's no problem with merging individual files. It's just not normally done because of this complication.

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly the kind of answer I was looking for!

Comment: Yet another reason to use Git